# cant update listView (android)

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

i was trying to code something(the world will never know what :D) and when im trying to update listview i just get an error....

code in theory: "when i click on item in NavDrawer the listView should get populated with specific data"

code in reality:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] values;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    values = new String[]{"Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
public void update(){
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

that method is called from this method that exsists in NavDrawerFragment.java

```
@Override
public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "shit is going down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    new MainActivity().update();

}
```

i guess that it is happening because im creating a new object, but i just (in the middle of typing a post) passed adapter as a method parameter(u can inmagine it as a setter)and in itemClicked method i  typed adapter.clear() and same shit happend

---

okay, i changed values varible using setter

```
 public void setValues(String[] values) {
    this.values = values;
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

i called it like that from recyclerview(that exists in the drawer) adapter
`String values[] = {"lel", "uja"};
            mainActivity.setValues(values);`
so same crash, maybile som1 would like to get on skype call? i promise, i wont be annoying

---

Apparently I was creating another object after all:

```
 MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
```

I was wondering why I can access that method like this:

```
mainActivity.setValues(values);
```

So probably what I'm asking is: How to access method without creating activity?

Comment: You called an instance of a new main activity? why

Comment: i was trying to access method(update()), accualy today i redid some of the code, i was hoping to find a bug and i wanted to change something, before i wasint creating an instance of MainActivity, i forgot how i did it (honestly i wasint thinking how to acces a method when i was redoing it so probobly thats why i called it)but in the middle of typing a post i thought that i should just try to acces adapter form antother class(itemClicked method) but same shit happend

Answer (score 1):

For an ArrayAdapter, notifyDataSetChanged only works if you use the `add()`, `insert()`, `remove()`, and `clear()` on the Adapter.

When an `ArrayAdapter` is constructed, it holds the reference for the `List` that was passed in. If you were to pass in a List that was a member of an `Activity`, and change that Activity member later, the `ArrayAdapter` is still holding a reference to the original List. The Adapter does not know you changed the List in the Activity.

```
 @Override
    public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
        //filter your list i.e `values` based on on item click,clearing it and adding new values
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: so i should change array values and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: i know what adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); does, i just was testing, even line like notifyDataSetChanged() crashed it

Comment: i probobly today gona try ur way, im busy atm